# Cython slowed down by prints

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cython

I was doing some tests prior to cythonizing some code of mine, and I've generated some weird behavior, as far as I'm concerned.

Browsing the web I've stumbled across a link that said that C-Like operations in cython are faster than numpy functions, and I thought that was weird, so I decided to test it.

The code I've used is:

cimport cython

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

import time


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

def main():
    # Test #1

    n = 100000000
    x = np.random.rand(n)

    start_time = time.time()

    s = x.sum()


    print("--- FINAL: {sec:1.5f} seconds ---".format(sec = time.time() - start_time))


    print(s)


    #Test #2

    cdef int n2 = 100000000

    cdef np.ndarray x2 = np.empty(n2, dtype = np.double)

    x2 = np.random.rand(n2)

    #x =

    start_time = time.time()

    s2 = x2.sum()


    print("--- FINAL: {sec:1.5f} seconds ---".format(sec = time.time() - start_time))


    print(s2)



    #Test #3
    cdef int n3 = n2
    cdef int i
    cdef double s3 = 0

    cdef np.ndarray x3 = np.empty(n3, dtype = np.double)

    x3 = np.random.rand(n3)


    cdef double [:] x3_view = x3




    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(n3):
        s3 += x3_view[i]


    print("--- FINAL: {sec:1.10f} seconds ---".format(sec = time.time() - start_time))

    print(s3) # THIS LINE
```

The weird part is:

When I run the code as it is presented I get:

```
--- FINAL: 0.12800 seconds ---
--- FINAL: 0.13792 seconds ---
--- FINAL: 0.1550407410 seconds ---
```

But when I comment the last line, the one indicated by `# THIS LINE`, I get:

```
--- FINAL: 0.13035 seconds ---
--- FINAL: 0.14981 seconds ---
--- FINAL: 0.0000000000 seconds ---
```

The extremely weird part is that the `print` statement that I refer to is not even enclosed by the `start_time` and `print seconds` statements.

Any clues on what is going on ?

Comment: Sounds to me like the `s3` computation was getting optimized out.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what that means ...

Comment: If you don't actually *use* `s3`, the C compiler is free to completely remove the loop that computes it.

Comment: (Why is test 3 using an input 100 times bigger than the others, anyway? It's very misleading.)

Comment: Oh, because it was so much faster that it was displaying 0 seconds, and I naively thought it was because it was much much faster...

Comment: I should edit that... will do. Anyhow when I use the same number the 3rd test is slower. Shouldn't it be about the same ?

Comment: Also, I think you got it right. Would like to answer the question ? I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think you may have gotten the timings reversed in your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cython compiles to C, and then the C compiler gets to optimize the result. When you don't actually use `s3`, the C compiler is free to completely remove the loop that computes `s3`, as the loop's only effect is to be slow.